# laravel 5.5 Multi auth error 'InvalidArgumentException Authentication user provider [] is not defined.'

Tags: php, laravel

The error is

> InvalidArgumentException 
>   …\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\CreatesUserProviders.php42

config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'adminss',
        ],
    ],
```

This is my Admin model

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $table = 'admins';


}
```

I've googled this error. But there aren't any solutions at all

**update:** 
Here's my provider array

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
            'drivers' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],

],
```

Comment: can you kindly give the 'providers' section in  config/auth.php

Comment: sorry for the delay. I've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have typo on your `config/auth.php`

```
'provider' => 'admins'
```

Comment: and typo again `'driver' => 'eloquent',`

Comment: Oh god. Yes. This is the error causing typo. Thanks